# Installable Python tar.gz package depends on OS used to build tarball

Tags: python, linux, gzip, tar, setup.py

I recently encountered the odd scenario where, I wanted to convert my (correctly formatted) Python package `coolpackage` into a tarball for simple distribution to some colleagues, yet the validity of the resulting tarball depends on the OS used to generate it.

For context, `coolpackage` can be installed from the source directory via `pip` on either macOS and Ubuntu Linux without issue:

```
cd coolpackage
pip install .
```

This works on both macOS and Linux, and in both cases is being run in a `conda` environment that is identical in terms of packages.

Now, if I generated a tarball  in Ubuntu

```
# run inside Ubuntu 18.04
tar -czvf coolpackage.tar.gz coolpackage
```

Then that `tar.gz` file can be installed using pip on both macOS and Ubuntu:

```
pip install coolpackage.tar.gz
```

However, if I generate a tarball in macOS

```
# run inside macOS Mojave
tar -czvf coolpackage.tar.gz coolpackage
```

*That* tarball is not installable on either macOS or Ubuntu and exits with basically the same error in both cases (paths notwithstanding):

```
    pip install coolpackage.tar.gz
    Processing ./coolpackage.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/alex/Python/conda/envs/localconda/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2n/xtzsyspd32v6vglg_pd5gmw80000gn/T/pip-req-build-tz8wnxlx/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2n/xtzsyspd32v6vglg_pd5gmw80000gn/T/pip-req-build-tz8wnxlx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/2n/xtzsyspd32v6vglg_pd5gmw80000gn/T/pip-req-build-tz8wnxlx/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/2n/xtzsyspd32v6vglg_pd5gmw80000gn/T/pip-req-build-tz8wnxlx/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/alex/Python/conda/envs/localconda/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/2n/xtzsyspd32v6vglg_pd5gmw80000gn/T/pip-req-build-tz8wnxlx/setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Wondering if anyone has encountered this before, or has thoughts on what might be going on? I can avoid this by building in Linux, so not an immediate issue, but I don't like not understanding *why* something fails.

Comment: maybe try to tar without z option _then_ gzip? (probably not the issue, but easy to test)

Comment: There are flavors/dialects of `tar` that are not entirely portable. If you want to use BSD version on Linux, try looking for `bsdtar`, if you want Linux (GNU) version on BSD (incl. Darwin -> MacOS) which seems to be your case, try looking for `gtar` instead of `tar`. This could be what throws `pip` off?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - nice idea, but that sadly did not work, will try with gtar when I get a moment!

Comment: Noone had problems on MacOS when everyone just played glider on it. good luck with your issue.

Comment: FYI using `gtar` works - @OndrejK. if you want to submit this as an 'answer' I can accept it. Not super satisfying as it's not clear to me why the BSD tar doesn't work, but this does offer a solution should someone else run into it

Comment: @Alex ACK. makes sense to close the loop... I am not a fan of of problems that have been solved. but the answer is actually buried in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various dialects / flavors of `tar` that are largely similar. In this case we're looking at GNU tools commonly used on Linux systems and BSD tools used on BSD (-> Darwin -> MacOS X).

If you want run BSD tar on Linux try `bsdtar` and if you want to use GNU tar on BSD (but also some other U*X systems), try `gtar`.

This also translate into other consumers of tarballs and it seems to be what trips `pip` which apparently expects GNU version (`gtar`) flavored inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Python, it could be a good idea to directly use [`python -m tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#command-line-options) and [`python -m gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#command-line-options) from its standard library. It should be portable enough.

Also, assuming the project is packaged with *setuptools* (or *distutils*) the using the *sdist* directly should be good enough in most cases (`python setup.py sdist`).

Comment: Thanks - this is probably *actually* solving the problem I'm trying to solve!